# Getting error when try to get Uris for multiple contacts emails via contentResolver query

Tags: kotlin, uri, photo, android-contentresolver

How to get photo Uris for multiple contacts emails

This code works fine for one email, but doesn't work for array of emails.

Error:
Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 1 parameters.

```
private fun getContactUri(email: Array<String>): Map<String, Uri?> {
        val contactsEmailsMapUri = mutableMapOf<String, Uri?>()
        val projection = arrayOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID)
        context.contentResolver.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS + " = ?",
            email,
            null
        )?.use { uriCursor ->
            val columnIndex = uriCursor.getColumnIndex(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID
            )

            while (uriCursor.moveToNext()) {
                val contactIdString = uriCursor.getString(columnIndex)
                val contactIdLong = uriCursor.getLong(columnIndex)
                val uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    contactIdLong
                )
                val uriPath = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    uri,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY
                )
                contactsEmailsMapUri.getOrPut(contactIdString) { uriPath }
            }
        }

        return contactsEmailsMapUri
    }
```